# How to make buttons automatically be as big as possible in navbar?

Tags: html, css

I have been able to do this in the past, but I've forgotten how.

I basically want my buttons to be as big as they can, in relation to each other, how many buttons there are, etc. It's kinda like a mobile navigation-bar.

[This](http://www.titanui.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/27/Navbar-Tabbar-UI-For-Mobile-PSD.jpg) is what I'm looking for, but it's supposed to be on the top but I don't remember how I did it, it was by accident I think and now I want it for my website that I'm developing.

Comment: You might just wanna use bootstrap navbars http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar

Comment: Thanks, but I don't want to have to use a pre-made kit, like Bootstrap. I want to build it from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

Calculate the width for each item by counting how many nav items you have and divide the number into 100. That will give you the percentage width of each item so that they are flush and span the container.

Example: 5 items
5/100 = 20%

```
li a {width:20%;}
```